# Failed to pass routeValues to an action from partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna add search functionality in my MVC application. This functionality should be available for all pages. So, I added it into the shared layout.

The only problem I have is that I'm not able to pass the routValues to the `Search` action in spite of I'm creating a new `Form` inside the partial view.

Target action:(performs the search)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel keyword)
{
    // keyword is always null
    return RedirectToAction("SearchResult", keyword.keyword);
}

public class SearchModel { public string Keyword { get; set; } }
```

The Partial View:

```
@model DocuLine.Models.SearchModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Keyword)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Comment: How are you creating that partial view? Are you passing in an instance of a SearchModel to it?

Comment: Yes, with just new empty instance

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is before redirecting. Because the parameter is passed null from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why the class is defined as `Keyword` and then view `SearchResult` you pass it as a `keyword` (lower case first letter)?

1 [UpdateModel](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/)

You can update the class `SearchModel` with the method `UpdateModel` to check if you can make the correct assignment.

2 `FormCollection`

You can try to receive as parameter in the method `Search` form data (`FormCollection`) and check if you get what you require.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve it. The problem is that the `SearchModel` parameter name is `keyword` and it should be anything except `keyword` becuase there's already an html control is rendered with this name.

To solve it, it should only be named with another name:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
{
     // model now has a value.
}
```

Comment: That was my answer ... public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)

Comment: Ya, thanks. really I didn't notice. I thought you were talking about redirect only.

Please, clarify it more to set it as the answer, just to let the other benefit from it. Thanks again.